# Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (50,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, keras, lstm, gensim

I got an error:

```
Error when checking input: 
expected embedding_1_input to have shape (50,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

When I change the input parameter `input_length` to 1, the error becomes:

```
Error when checking input: 
expected embedding_1_input to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (50,)
```

My code is as below:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer, TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
import os
from keras import metrics
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM, Bidirectional, BatchNormalization, Activation, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing import sequence, text
import pandas as pd
from gensim import corpora
from gensim import models

maxlen = 50
batch_size = 128
np.random.seed(7)

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/DMY/Peer-logic-master/newdata/topnine.csv',encoding='utf-8')

x = df["REVIEW"].fillna("na").values  
y = df["TAG"]
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
y = encoder.transform(y)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.1)

word_list = []

for i in range(len(x_train)):
    word_list.append(x_train[i].split(' '))


dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(word_list)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in word_list]


tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)

X_train_id = [] 
word_id_dict = dictionary.token2id
for i in range(len(word_list)):
    sen_id = []
    word_sen = word_list[i]
    for j in range(len(word_sen)):       
        id = word_id_dict.get(word_sen[j])
        if id is None:
            id = 0 
        sen_id.append(id)
    X_train_id.append(sen_id)

X_train_tfidf_vec = []  
for i in range(len(x_train)):
    temp = {}
    string = x_train[i]
    string_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(string.lower().split()) 
    string_tfidf = tfidf[string_bow]

    for j in range(len(string_tfidf)):
#         print(string_tfidf[j][0])
        temp[string_tfidf[j][0]] = string_tfidf[j][1]
#         print(temp)
    X_train_tfidf_vec.append(temp)

X_train_tfidf = []  
for i in range(len(X_train_id)):
    sen_id = X_train_id[i]
    sen_id_tfidf = X_train_tfidf_vec[i]
    sen = []
    for j in range(len(sen_id)):
        word_id = sen_id[j]
        word_tfidf = sen_id_tfidf.get(word_id)
        if word_tfidf is None:
            word_tfidf = 0
        sen.append(word_tfidf)
    X_train_tfidf.append(sen)

x_train_tfidf = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train_tfidf, maxlen=maxlen,dtype='float64')
#print(len(x_train_tfidf))
#print(x_train_tfidf)

model4 = Sequential()
model4.add(Embedding(len(x_train_tfidf)+1, 100, input_length = ))#input_dim,output_dim,input_length
model4.add(Dropout(0.6))
model4.add(LSTM(100, recurrent_dropout=0.6))
model4.add(Dropout(0.6))
model4.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model4.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model4_history = model4.fit(x_train_tfidf, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=7,
                            validation_split=0.1)
score4, acc4 = model4.evaluate(x_test, y_test,
                               batch_size=batch_size)
print('Test accuracy for LSTM Model is:', acc4)
y_pred4 = model4.predict(x_test)
y_pred4 = (y_pred4 > 0.5)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred4))
```

Comment: Hope someone can help me solve it. Great thanks.

Comment: Show the full error message & associated stack, in your question, so that answerers can easily see exactly which line(s) & variables are involved.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/), the embedding layer takes a number of different initialization parameters.

```py
Embedding(input_dim, 
          output_dim, 
          embeddings_initializer='uniform', 
          embeddings_regularizer=None, 
          activity_regularizer=None, 
          embeddings_constraint=None, 
          mask_zero=False, 
          input_length=None)
```

Note that `input_dim` specifies the vocabulary size of the input data, *i.e.* how many different words there are in the data. The `output_dim` specifies the dimensionality of the latent space, *i.e.* how long the vector for each word will be after the embedding transformation.

Let's put this into perspective with an example. Consider the following layer:

```py
model.add(Embedding(1000, 64, input_length=10))
```

This specifies the fact that

- There are 1000 unique words in the data
- Each word will be represented as 64-dimensional vectors
- Instances in the data will be phrases of 10 words

The output of this layer will be of shape `(None, 10, 64)`, where `None` is the batch size. In your case, `input_length` should probably set to be equal to `maxlen`, which seems to specify the size of each instance in the input data.